# Reactjs Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, unexpected-token

This is my code below, and when I tried to run it on localhost, nothing shows up, and in the console it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". (in line  "

```
    const { render }=ReactDOM

    const style={
        backgroundColor:'orange',
        color:'white',
        fontFamily:'verdana'
    }



    render(
        <h1 id='title'
        className='header'
        style={style}>
        Hello World
        </h1>,
        document.getElementById('react-container')
    )
```

I checked several times but can't figure out what I did wrong. 
There is a index.html file and index.js file, above is the code from index.js file

Comment: You should go check react doc before posting here

Comment: Is that really _all_ the code in `index.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You must import react to make use of JSX.

try to add this to the top of your code:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it says  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on import React from 'react', do u might know what's the matter

Comment: let me see your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Before everything, you must install the **react** dependency to your project. Install nodejs in your computer, then in the terminal, go to your project directory and run `npm init`. After you answer the questions, still inside your project folder, you need to run `npm install --save react react-dom`

Then, your final `index.js` code must look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const style={
        backgroundColor:'orange',
        color:'white',
        fontFamily:'verdana'
    }

ReactDOM.render(<h1 id='title'
        className='header'
        style={style}>
        Hello World
        </h1>, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```